# attach 2 functions in form with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I  have this html form

```
<form action="upload/" id="upload" name="upload">
// other form data
</form>
```

and this in html on page where i can switch form attributes

```
<a href="#" id="startDownload">Download</a>
<a href="#" id="startUpload">Upload</a>
```

and my javascript

```
$("#startUpload").click(function( {
    $("form").attr('action','upload/').attr('id','upload');
});

$("#startDownload").click(function( {
    $("form").attr('action','download/').attr('id','download');
});

$(function() {
    $('#upload').uploadThis({
        // other code here
    });
$(function() {
    $('#download').downloadThis({
        // other code here
    });
```

my problem is when i click on href #startUpload this is attached with $('#upload').uploadThis({}) function and it works but when i click on #startDownload it is not attaching this $('#upload').downloadThis({}) function and not getting called.

thanks for any help.

Comment: Your code misses a lot of `}` and `)`. You should correct it, it's easier to get the picture then. What is also `.uploadThis({...})` applied on jquery objects ? Some sort of plugins ?

Comment: thanks Didier, actually above code i just wrote for demonstration, actual code is very long so i thought if i could get the logic with above code. Regards

Comment: here is actual code i am using, its a progress bar plugin http://paste2.org/p/1814577.  Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what is the wanted behavior but changing IDs of elements always brings the same sort of issues.

You are doing this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#upload').uploadThis({
        // other code here
    });
});

$(function() {
    $('#download').downloadThis({
        // other code here
    });
});
```

`$(<Function>);` is a shorthand for `$(document).ready(<Function>);`

The thing is that when you're document is ready, it will execute both your handlers above **but** at that time, **only an element with ID #upload exists**, `$('#download')` will actually be an empty selection.

What you could do is call `$('#upload').uploadThis()` and `$('#download').downloadThis()` in your respective `.click()` handlers after changing the IDs.

```
$("#startUpload").click(function( {
    $("form")
       .attr({ 'action': 'upload/', 'id': 'upload' })
       .uploadThis(...);
});
```

Note: if those are plugins you wrote yourself, be sure that they won't initialize each time you call them.

Hope I'm clear enough :o)

Comment: thank you sir, yes i understand now that #download was not in document so it did not run, you above logic will work if i will attach only to .click event but on page load i must initialize $('#upload').uploadThis() once. thanks for any input

Comment: i just added all functions in submit button with above method, all fixed, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as many times as you like:

```
$("#startDownload").bind('click', function() {
    ...
});
```

Comment: `.click()` is a shorthand for `.bind('click', ...)`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to bind elements before they exist on DOM... will never work.

```
$("#startUpload").click(function( {
    $("form").attr('action','upload/').attr('id','upload').submit(function() {
        $(this).uploadThis({
            //other code here
        });
    );
});

$("#startDownload").click(function( {
    $("form").attr('action','download/').attr('id','download').submit(function() {
        $(this).downloadThis({
            //other code here
        });
    );
});
```

THis way you will bind the action you want in the submit form event. Probably will fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach would be to make custom events for the form and trigger them by the onclick's:

```
$("#startUpload").click(function( {
    $("form").trigger('upload');
});
$("#startDownload").click(function( {
    $("form").trigger('download');
});

$("form").bind('upload',function(){
    $(this).attr('action','upload/').uploadThis();
}).bind('download',function(){
    $(this).attr('action','download/').downloadThis();
});
```

Comment: thank sir, i tested this method and it works as expected. here is my actual code http://paste2.org/p/1814811, now i also wants to have uploadThis() on page load, how would i achieve it? Regards